# What's the simplest way to get the IP address of a Google Compute Engine Instance in Python?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

If I know the region and name of an instance, what's the simplest way to get the instance's public IP address?

```
def get_public_ip(region, instance_name):
    # ???
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ipaddresses

Comment: You think the easiest way is to make a shell call to gcutil? I was kind of hoping that using the Python API would be easier.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what you already know.  You haven't said much about what you've tried, or what research you've already done.

Comment: There's an example of listing all instances at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python-guide#listinginstances but it's not completely clear to me how much of that boilerplate is required. Also the GCE Python docs tend to be somewhat unreliable, so I was hoping someone with GCE experience might be able to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Does listing the instance give you the IP?

Comment: It does in gcutil listinstances, so I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Well, everything in that code snippet looks like it's necessary.  You have to set up a session, authenticate, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using gcutil:

```
$ gcutil listinstances --columns=external-ip
```

or using python api `networkInterfaces` structure looks like:

```
u'networkInterfaces':[
  {
     u'accessConfigs':[
        {
           u'kind':u'compute#accessConfig',
           u'type':u'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT',
           u'name':u'External NAT',
           u'natIP':u'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
        }
     ],
     u'networkIP':u'10.xxx.xxx.xxx',
     u'network': u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<my-project-id>/global/networks/<network-name>',
     u'name':u'nic0'
  }
```

]

so you can use [this Listing Instances example](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/python-guide#listinginstances) to do something like:

```
for instance in instances:
    print instance['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
api = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = api.instances().get(project=project_id, zone=region, instance=instance_name).execute()

ip = response['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
```

returns the *external IP* listed in the compute engine front end