# What's the way to get in java a GCP managed-Instance external IP?

Tags: java, google-api, java-8, google-cloud-platform

I have a list of `List<ManagedInstance>`

I'm looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616960/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-ip-address-of-a-google-compute-engine-instanc) equivalant in java-8 - how to find an external ip of a `ManagedInstance` ?

I saw in the java-doc, but found no "external IP" property.

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public final class ManagedInstance extends   /**
   * [Output only] The unique identifier for this resource. This field is empty when instance does
   * not exist.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key @com.google.api.client.json.JsonString
  private java.math.BigInteger id;

  /**
   * [Output Only] The URL of the instance. The URL can exist even if the instance has not yet been
   * created.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.String instance;

  /**
   * [Output Only] The status of the instance. This field is empty when the instance does not exist.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.String instanceStatus;

...
```